# remove borders of input jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

How can I quit the borders of a input in JQuery Mobile?

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
 <label for="textinput_nick" class="ui-hidden-accessible" data-t="form_nick"></label>
 <input type="text" name="nick" id="textinput_nick" placeholder="form_nick" value="" data-mini="true" maxlength="80">
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of **jQuery Mobile 1.4**, you can apply custom CSS to `input` without any JS intervention. Create a custom class and add it to `input` by using `data-wrapper-class` attribute.

Custom CSS

```
.ui-input-text.ui-custom {
   border: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Add it to `input`

```
<input type="text" data-wrapper-class="ui-custom" />
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2hm5o94p/)**

---

In jQuery Mobile 1.3 & earlier, `input` is invisible and replaced with a div `.ui-input-text` that holds all styles.

To remove border, you need to remove it from `.ui-input-text` not `input` itself as it's invisible.

```
.ui-input-text {
  border: none;
}
```

To remove *inner shadow*, you have to do it in JS. Wrap your code in `pagecreate` to take effect once per page.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
  $(".ui-input-text").removeClass("ui-shadow-inset");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/m7z8g/)**

Comment: Thank you, and where I have to put this js? onpageshow?

Comment: This answer applies to ALL elements. How do I do the same for SOME elements, say, the ones with :read-only or with a specific id?

http://jsfiddle.net/m7z8g/10/

Answer (score 0):

Note: As of https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7781 the wrapper-class will become deprecated.

At the moment I'm using JS like

```
$("input").closest(".ui-input-text").addClass("no-glow");
```